# Is this possible without template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I need to make a class that accepts a function pointer, stores it, and then runs it. Let's also assume that the function that this class accepts can either return `void`, or `cReturnValue`; there are also other requirements and template arguments in my real code, which are irrelevant to the question.

Now, if the return type is `void`, I need to simply run the function. If the return type is `cReturnValue`, I need to run it, get the result, and use it. Is it possible to handle both cases in a single template, without using partial specialization?

```
template< typename Function, typename ReturnType > class Executor
{
public:
    Executor(Function f) : _f(f) {}
    void run()
    {
        //I know this will not work, but is this possible somehow?
        if(std::is_same<ReturnType, void>::value)
        {
            _f();
        }
        else if(std::is_same<ReturnType, cReturnValue>::value)
        {
            cReturnValue val = _f();
            //do some stuff with val
        }
    }

private:
    Function _f;
};
```

Comment: Since there is no `static_if` in C++ - you should use specialization.

Comment: @ForEveR :There is "staticif", it's std::conditional. Btw you can use SFINAE for this.

Comment: Without specialising the class template? Yes. Without any specialisation? Probably not.

Comment: @DanielJour how about tag-dispatching, hugh?

Comment: @DanielJour: i think it can be solved with SFINAE-->No specialization at all.

Comment: @Melkon How would you do that "in a single template"?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You mean dispatching to two different functions depending on the value of the is_same check? What type do you give to the equivalent of `cReturnValue` ? It can't be `void`

Comment: @DanielJour: ForEveR already wrote it as an answer, specialization not needed.

Comment: @DanielJour I mean dispatching depending on `ReturnType`, [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32327836/3953764)

Comment: @Melkon Indeed, I forgot overloads. And tag dispatching, though I was actually working on something very similar to Piotr's answer.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I completely misunderstood what you meant. This is of course very possible and a nice solution. I guess you could use `std::result_of` to determine the return type.

Comment: @DanielJour i thought the same, but this is allowing you to store the return value as a different type, so with this solution you can do this: `Base* = _f();` while _f() returning Derived*. If it's not the case i would prefer to eliminate ReturnType template parameter too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use tag-dispatching:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename Function, typename ReturnType>
class Executor
{
public:
    Executor(Function f) : _f(f) {}

    void run()
    {
        run(tag<ReturnType>{});
    }

private:
    void run(tag<cReturnValue>)
    {
        cReturnValue val = _f();
    }

    void run(tag<void>)
    {
        _f();
    }

    Function _f;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adb7784b0d9f960b)

Answer (score 4):

I think you cannot do such thing with single template. But you can use SFINAE for this. Something like this is very simple way to do this:

```
private:
    template<typename R>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<R, void>::value>::type run_()
    {
       _f();
    }

    template<typename R>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<R, void>::value>::type run_()
    {
       ReturnType val = _f();
       // do some stuff with val
    }
```

and run will be just

```
void run()
{
   run_<ReturnType>();
}
```